# How to get laravel relationship to work?

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to learn how to get a role name from the role table by linking it to the user table with role_id in user table and user_id in the role table.

below is what I've got, working through a couple of naming errors I've ended up here.

How do I go about making this work?

Works: Outputs '4'

```
{{ Auth::user()->role_id }}
```

Doesn't: Outputs nothing

```
{{ Auth::user()->role['name'] }}
```

Errors: Trying to get property of non-object (View:

```
{{ Auth::user()->role->name }}
```

relationships:

```
User model:

public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
}

Role model:

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Full Role class:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
  //

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

}
```

Comment: User model should have `role()` relationship instead :), also you can access user instance using `auth()->user();`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be this

User model:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
}
```

Role model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then

```
{{ Auth::user()->role->name }}
```

Comment: This causes: Class 'App\Role' not found to happen.

Comment: I would have assumed the Role model was App\Role. what is the class name of your Role model?

Comment: class Role extends Model. So i also assumed it was App\Role. I have a RoleController to go with it and a role view.

Comment: If class Role is in your 'App' namespace then it should find it. can you show your complete Role class?

Comment: Edited question with the full class

Comment: yeah, your namespace is Laravel. Either change to 'App' or change reference to 'Laravel\Role'. This is a separate issue now and has to do with your setup, not your original question.

Comment: Thanks. ill make a new question regarding this .